# Convert text to XML using XSLT without knowing what the "schema" would be

Tags: xml, xslt, text

I have a text document that I want to convert to XML using XSLT for easier processing.
the source file is pretty general, such as this:

```
[{c=1,d=2},{cc=11,dd=22}]%{f=4,g=5,h={i=6,j=[7,8]}}%
```

I'd like to transform this to an XML file such as this:

```
<document>
    <header>
        <item>
            <c>1</c>
            <d>2</d>
        </item>
        <item>
            <cc>11</c>
            <dd>22</d>
        </item>
    </header>
    <content>
        <f>4</f>
        <g>5</g>
        <h>
            <i>6</i>
            <j>
                <elt>7</elt>
                <elt>8</elt>
            </j>
        </h>
    </content>
</document>
```

So in essence, the string before an "=" is the tag name, everything thereafter is the content (with nesting), with the only addition of the document, header, content and elt nodes. The original file will likely contain each value and all "}" on separate lines but that is not guaranteed(I don't know if that matters or not)

I found some answers for similar cases where text is converted to XML, but there the resulting node names and nesting levels are always know beforehand.
Gut feeling there should be a relatively simple solution to this, but unfortunately I know only that XSLT is powerful and useful, but not who to write it...

Thanks in advance for the help,
DeColaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael suggested, this indeed looks like a nice exercise for [REx](http://bottlecaps.de/rex/). The sample shows some similarity to [JSON](http://www.json.org/), but for demonstration, let's guess an even simpler REx grammar:

```
source     ::= item '%' item '%' eof
item       ::= '{' ( named-item ( ',' named-item )* )? '}'
             | '[' ( item ( ',' item )* )? ']'
             | element
named-item ::= name '=' item
<?TOKENS?>
name       ::= [a-z]+
element    ::= [0-9]+
eof        ::= $
```

Put it in a file named `source.ebnf`, and use REx to generate an XSLT-coded parser from it, by configuring options `XSLT` and `parse tree`, or using command line `-xslt -tree`.

The parser contains a function named `p:parse-source` that accepts the input as a string and turns it into a concrete syntax tree according to the above grammar. The syntax tree contains an element for each nonterminal or named token, and a TOKEN element for each unnamed token.

That syntax tree then must be transformed into the target structure. Import the generated parser from file `source.xslt` into the XSLT below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:p="source">

  <xsl:import href="source.xslt"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="input" select="'[{c=1,d=2},{cc=11,dd=22}]%{f=4,g=5,h={i=6,j=[7,8]}}%'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="parse-tree" select="p:parse-source($input)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($parse-tree/self::source)">
        <xsl:sequence select="$parse-tree"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="item">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$parse-tree/item"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="document">
          <xsl:element name="header">
            <xsl:sequence select="$item/*[1]/node()"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="content">
            <xsl:sequence select="$item/*[2]/node()"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="items">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::TOKEN)]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($items/*) eq 1">
        <xsl:sequence select="$items"/>      
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="item">
          <xsl:sequence select="$items"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="named-item">
    <xsl:element name="{name}">
      <xsl:variable name="item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:sequence select="$item/*/node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:element name="elt">
       <xsl:sequence select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running the above on an XSLT 2.0 processor, e.g. Saxon, will generate the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically trying to write a parser for some grammar. Which is quite feasible to do, but it helps to know exactly what the grammar is, and it helps to know a little bit about how to write a recursive descent parser. From your sample it looks like a recursive grammar, which means you can't do it purely using regular expressions.

You might like to take a look at Rex, Gunther Rademacher's tool for generating parsers in XQuery or (recently) XSLT. It's not well documented but it's very powerful.

Comment: Indeed knowing the grammar would help, but unfortunately that does not exist. I do know that my sample appears to cover everything I can expect, and indeed it is recursive.

Comment: If you don't know what input your program is required to handle, don't even attempt to write the program. If you do know, then you can write the grammar for it.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 there is a function called `unparsed-text()` which will parse an HREF (or file) and return a string.

You could then use one or more of the regular expression instructions or functions (such as `tokenize()` or `xsl:analyze-string`) to break the string up into a sequence and process the parts.

Elements can be created in a stylesheet using the `xsl:element` instruction, like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="elementName" select="'f'"/>
<xsl:element name="$elementName">
  ..
</xsl:elelent>
```

Obviously you would be getting the element name from your string, but hopefully you see the pattern used.